# Can't see mail log when using PHPMailer but if I use simple php mail() function i can see log

Tags: php, email, logging, wamp, phpmailer

**php.ini**

```
mail.log = "c:/wamp/logs/maillog.log"
```

**PHPMailer_Email.php**
*(Using below script, it doesn't write log in specified file but send email.)*

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->Host = "domain.example.net";
  $mail->Port = 25;
  $mail->From = $from;
  $mail->FromName = "From Name";
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->addReplyTo($from, "Reply");
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = $body;
  $mail->AltBody = $body;
  if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo; die();
  }
  else{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
  }
```

**Email.php** *(Using below script, it write log and also send email)*

```
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

**Could anyone suggest how I can enable PHPMailer to write mail log in maillog.log file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local log file is for your local mail server, but you're sending directly to an external server, so it's not going through your local server, so there's nothing to log. If you want to capture debug output and log it, look at the options provided with the `Debugoutput` property - you can inject a callable and make it save wherever you like, like this:

```
$mail->DebugOutput = function ($str, $level) {
  file_put_contents(
    '/path/to/log/file',
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\t" . $str,
    FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
  );
};
```